# How to Add processBar inside QTreeWidget cloum

Tags: c++, qt

Is there any way in Qt to Add a processBar inside one of QTreeWidget items
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8mwF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#setItemWidget will do the job for you

just call it for each row with whatever widget you need.

cheers

/edit:

lets say your column 'status' has column index `5`, then it would be something like this:

```
QTreeWidgetItem* item = new QTreeWidgetItem(columnTextsStringList);
/*insert into tree here*/
QProgressBar* progBar = new QProgressBar;
treeWidget->setItemWidget(item, 5/*column of the status*/, progBar);
// no need to delete progBar, its now a child of treeWidget
// use progBar
```